# Method to convert glade XML designed for GTK2.24 to one usable with GTK3? Python usage

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, glade

My version of glade (3.40) continues crashing so it is impossible to design the same UI via the glade for gtk3. I have an xml for gtk2.24 and need to convert it to have similar functionality in gtk3.

I have been looking for hours for xml documentation to see whether the xml can be converted directly.

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried using glade (3.40) and it crashes on any icon (ico file) loading as well as different tasks.

I tried using GPT4 for converting the xml but it does not work as GPT does not have knowledge on specific changes to xml file writing from glade 2 to glade 3.